# AS3 USB game controller support

Tags: actionscript-3, browser, controller, usb

How can I make a USB controller control my AS3 game. I'm using the keyboard right now and I have thought about mapping the keys but I have to use a plugin for that and I just want users to be able to buy a simple controller that doesn't need any driver downloads/configuration. They should be able to plugin the USB controller and play the game through Flash Player in a browser.

Comment: If you can wait, the next release of Flash (codenamed "Molehill") will be supporting game controllers. They demonstrated Microsoft's Xbox controller and a Logitech steering wheel at MAX this year.

Comment: I was hoping someone would mention this. When will it be out? Where is the documentation on it?

Comment: @Sam - "Gaming device support in Flash Player is in its early stages, and we have not yet finalized dates for its availability in a future public release." - from http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flash/molehill/

Comment: @Allan:  very cool!  i didn't know this.

Comment: @allan, well if you guys want gamers to make stuff for Flash better get on it! Is there any truth to the first half of 2011 release?

Comment: @Sam - who knows, I hope so :) but I imagine they would want to release it as soon as possible, of course it is a mammoth job to make sure everything works correctly on such vast array of systems and devices. At least what they demonstrated looked pretty solid. Some footage here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlNKJbDrYdU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility... you can tell your users to download joy2key. http://electracode.com/4/joy2key/JoyToKey%20English%20Version.htm

I admit that this is not a "real answer" to your question. But it is a stop-gap solution until you figure out and implement the real solution.

Comment: Thanks, this is only PC though.

Comment: @Sam: There exist similar solutions in Linux. In fact, I use them every time I play in Linux. Joystick to Keyboard solutions are great. I don't know about Mac, but I'd assume something exists there too.